# What is android ContentObserver, how it handel with example I mean full tutorial "basic to advance" about ContentObserver. Please help me

Tags: android

I want to learn about android ContentObserver. What is android ContentObserver, how it handel with example I mean full tutorial "basic to advance" about ContentObserver. Why I use android ContentObserver? I want to learn. Please help me.

Comment: please do some search in google if you want sample code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a callback mechanism to receive notifications of changes on a [`Uri`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html). You register it with [`ContentResolver.registerContentObserver()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#registerContentObserver(android.net.Uri,%20boolean,%20android.database.ContentObserver)). Whenever someone notifies that a change has occurred for that Uri (using [`ContentResolver.notifyChange()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#notifyChange(android.net.Uri,%20android.database.ContentObserver))), registered observers will be called so that they can take some action, usually to re-query to get the updated content.

Comment: Thanks "Karakuri" for help me. I just know it, but I want to learn more with example. have you any reference link or book more about this topics? Again thanks to you.

Comment: What specifically do you need to know besides what's written? There's not much else to it. If you are trying to decide whether you need this mechanism in your app, perhaps explain what it is you are trying to accomplish and someone can tell you if this is the best way to achieve that result.